# Is it possible to resize MTD partitions at runtime?

Tags: linux, partition, flash-memory

I have a very specific need:
to partially replace the content of a flash **and** to move MTD partition boundaries.

Current map is:

- `u-boot     0x000000 0x040000`
- `u-boot-env 0x040000 0x010000`
- `kernel     0x050000 0x230000`
- `initrd     0x280000 0x170000`
- `scripts    0x3f0000 0x010000`
- `filesystem 0x400000 0xbf0000`
- `firmware   0xff0000 0x010000`

While desired output is:

- `u-boot     0x000000 0x040000`
- `u-boot-env 0x040000 0x010000`
- `kernel     0x050000 0x230000`
- `filesystem 0x280000 0xd70000`
- `firmware   0xff0000 0x010000`

This means to collapse `initrd`, `scripts` and `filesystem` into a single area while leaving the others alone.

Problem is this should be achieved from the running system (booted with the "old" configuration") **and** I should rewrite kernel and "new" filesystem before rebooting.

The system is an embedded, so I have little space for maneuver (I have a SD card, though).

Of course the rewritten kernel will have "new" configuration written in its DTB.

Problem is transition.

Note: I have seen [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836715/resize-mtd-partitions-at-runtime), but it is very old and it has drawback to need kernel patches, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I still think this is the more appropriate forum for this Q. I would recommend offering a bounty for an answer. That will bring it to the attention of more readers. Good luck!